# Classes returned from class factory have different IDs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, factory-method

I have a class factory method that is used to instantiate an object. With multiple objects are created through this method, I want to be able to compare the classes of the objects. When using `isinstance`, the comparison is False, as can be seen in the simple example below. Also running `id(a.__class__)` and `id(b.__class__)`, gives different ids.

Is there a simple way of achieving this? I know that this does not exactly conform to duck-typing, however this is the easiest solution for the program I am writing.

```
def factory():
    class MyClass(object):
        def compare(self, other):
            print('Comparison Result: {}'.format(isinstance(other, self.__class__)))
    return MyClass()

a = factory()
b = factory()

print(a.compare(b))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of defining a new class time you call `factory`?

Comment: If you want a function that creates a new instance of the same class every time it is called, such a function already exists: the class itself.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. This example is the least possible code needed to replicate the issue. The actual implementation is much more detailed, and involves the factory method belonging to an object, and certain interfaces between the parent and child.

Comment: I think that the example code that you put oversimplifies the problem so that answers cannot adequately contain a solution. Put in, if not the exact code, then an example with the "interfaces" and the "belonging to an object", etc.

Comment: Yeah. As rare as this is, I think you've made your example *too minimal* for us to fully comprehend the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `MyClass` is created dynamically every time you run `factory`. If you `print(id(MyClass))` inside `factory` you get different results:

```
>>> a = factory()
140465711359728
>>> b = factory()
140465712488632
```

This is because they are actually different classes, dynamically created and locally scoped at the time of the call.

One way to fix this is to return (or `yield`) multiple instances:

```
>>> def factory(n):
    class MyClass(object):
        def compare(self, other):
            print('Comparison Result: {}'.format(isinstance(other, self.__class__)))
    for i in range(n):
        yield MyClass()


>>> a, b = factory(2)
>>> a.compare(b)
Comparison Result: True
```

is a possible implementation.

EDIT: If the instances are created dynamically, then the above solution is invalid. One way to do it is to create a superclass outside, then inside the factory function subclass from that superclass:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    pass

>>> def factory():
    class SubClass(MyClass):
        def compare(self, other):
            print('Comparison Result: {}'.format(isinstance(other, self.__class__)))
    return SubClass()
```

However, this does not work because they are still different classes. So you need to change your comparison method to check against the first superclass:

```
isinstance(other, self.__class__.__mro__[1])
```

Comment: Thank you @rassar for your input. I really like your example, however the objects are actually created on demand from user interaction in the GUI, so I cannot create them at the same time.

Comment: @StuartBuckingham I have edited to include another solution, creating them based on a superclass that all dynamically created classes will share.

Comment: Wow, this is really nice! Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

If your `class` definition is inside the factory function, than each instance of the class you create will be an instance of *a separate class*. That's because the `class` definition is a statement, that's executed just like any other assignment. The name and contents of the different classes will be the same, but their identities will be distinct.

I don't think there's any simple way to get around that without changing the structure of your code in some way. You've said that your actual factory function is a method of a class, which suggests that you might be able to move the class definition somewhere else so that it can be shared by multiple calls to the factory method. Depending on what information you expect the inner class to use from the outer class, you might define it at class level (so there'd be only one class definition used everywhere), or you could define it in another method, like `__init__` (which would create a new inner class for every instance of the outer class).

Here's what that last approach might look like:

```
class Outer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        class Inner(object):
            def compare(self, other):
                print('Comparison Result: {}'.format(isinstance(other, self.__class__)))
        self.Inner = Inner

    def factory(self):
        return self.Inner()

f = Outer()
a = f.factory()
b = f.factory()
print(a.compare(b)) # True

g = Outer() # create another instance of the outer class
c = g.factory()
print(a.compare(c)) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. It seems to me you want a simpler version of the code you already posted. If that's incorrect, this answer is not relevant.

You can create classes dynamically by explicitly constructing a new instance of the `type` type.

```
def compare(self, other):
        ...

def factory():
    return type("MyClass", (object,), { 'compare': compare }()
```

`type` takes three arguments: the name, the parents, and the predefined slots. So this will behave the same way as your previous code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP meant that they want `factory` to always return the same type of class, and they want that class to be defined inside factory. I like your implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

Working off the answer from @rassar, and adding some more detail to represent the actual implementation (e.g. the factory-method existing in a parent class), I have come up with a working example below.

From @rassar's answer, I realised that the class is dynamically created each time, and so defining it within the parent object (or even above that), means that it will be the same class definition each time it is called.

```
class Parent(object):
    class MyClass(object):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def compare(self, other):
            print('Comparison Result: {}'.format(isinstance(other, self.__class__)))

    def factory(self):
        return self.MyClass(self)


a = Parent()
b = a.factory()
c = a.factory()

b.compare(c)
print(id(b.__class__))
print(id(c.__class__))
```